# load html code into gin framework template

Tags: html, go, static-files

I am new to go and [gin framework]https://gin-gonic.com/
I have an HTML file like this
`example.html`

```html
<div>
    <p> text for test <p>
    <p><img src="https://clipartcraft.com/images/google-logo-transparent-alphabet.png" alt="sampleImage"/></p>
    <p> text for test <p>
</div>
```

that I want load that in content part of this template
`index.tmpl`

```html
<html>
    <h1>
        {{ .title }}
    </h1>
        {{ .content }}
</html>
```

with this code:
`main.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}

func main() {
    dat, err := os.ReadFile("./example.html")
    check(err)

    router := gin.Default()
    router.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*")
    router.GET("/index", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.tmpl", gin.H{
            "title":   "Main website",
            "content": string(dat),
        })
    })
    router.Run(":8080")
}
```

It is not work and gin show source code(html) not render as HTML file like image etc...
How should load an HTML code in my template that gin render this as HTML.
HTML code can be read from a file (like this example) or call from a database later

Comment: `"content": template.HTML(dat),`. In other words, convert the raw html data to the [`template.HTML`](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template@go1.19.4#HTML) type.

Comment: Thanks how should I mark your comment as answer?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks [mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva)
`"content": template.HTML(dat),`